# How to download this image with Python?

Tags: python, urllib, urlretrieve

I have a direct link like this: https://picjumbo.com/download/?d=cow.jpg&n=cow&id=1. But I cannot download it using `urllib.request.urlretrieve()` because when I access this url, the browser will download it automatically.

Comment: why would you open the browser if you just want to write a script to download a certain image?

Comment: My code is used to automatically download images from a web page automatically. The above question is only a small one in my general code. I will not waste time writing code to load only a single image. But thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
>>> import requests
>>> content = requests.get('https://picjumbo.com/wp-content/themes/picjumbofree/run.php?download&d=cow.jpg&n=cow').content
>>> with open('downloaded_img.jpg', 'wb') as img:
...     img.write(content)
... 
8153739
>>>
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that and I was intending to change it after copying here but I forgot